# Possible to used a named variable as multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, magic-numbers

I have some simple code:

```
 context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

I was wondering if it would be possible, using something like ES6 spread (edit: spread syntax, not 'spread operator') features, to eliminate the magic numbers and make the code more explicit:

```
 const TOP_LEFT = [0, 0]
 context.drawImage(image, ...[TOP_LEFT]);
```

**Is there a way I can use a variable as multiple arguments in a function call?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes — exactly the way you did, but without `[]` around it when you use it:

```
context.drawImage(image, ...TOP_LEFT);
```

Live Example:

```js
function drawImage(image, x, y) {
  console.log("image = " + image);
  console.log("x = " + x);
  console.log("y = " + y);
}

const TOP_LEFT = [0, 0]
drawImage("the image", ...[TOP_LEFT]);
```

Now, you might not want to do that in a tight loop of thousands of iterations, because in theory and as specified, `...TOP_LEFT` involves calling a function on the array to create an iterator object, and then repeatedly calling a method on that iterator which creates a result object each time, and getting a property from that result object. But all of that is potentially subject to optimization, and in any case, we generally want to avoid worrying about performance until/unless there's a specific performance problem to address.

You might help the optimizer by [freezing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) your array:

```
const TOP_LEFT = Object.freeze([0, 0]);
```

...but you'd want to test your target environments to see if that's actually useful.

---

Side note: `...` isn't an operator, and couldn't be. An operator, like a function, has a single result value. Spread (and rest) are primary syntax, not operators, like `for` statements, function declarations, and object initializers.

Comment: This works perfectly - I'll accept it when the timer runs out. I don't know who the downvoter is, that's very rude for them downvote without providing any feedback.

Comment: @mikemaccana - Glad that helped. In general, it's perfectly fine to downvote without leaving a comment, and *explaining* downvotes is discouraged by Stack Exchange. But leaving a comment saying what you think is wrong, without actively saying "I downvoted because..." can be useful. Whenever someone downvotes my answer, the first thing I do is say "Oh dear, where have I messed up?" and double-check things. So even without a comment, often useful. But when I know the answer is correct, I do sometimes ask for clarification...

Comment: @Nick I searched for duplicates before I asked and couldn't find anything. Where are they? You haven't marked it as a duplicate either.